# For what values of a will the system have a unique solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Consider a linear system whose augmented matrix is of the form $$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1&2&1&1\\
      -1&4&3&2\\
       2&-2&a&3
    \end{array}
\right] $$

For what values of a will the system have a unique solution?

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1&2&1&1\\
      -1&4&3&2\\
       2&-2&a&3
    \end{array}
\right] \to \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1&2&1&1\\
      0&6&4&3\\
       0&-6&a-2&1
    \end{array}
\right] \to \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1&2&1&1\\
      0&6&4&3\\
       0&0&a+2&4
    \end{array}
\right] $$

The system has a unique solution because is consistent and a+2≠0 and a≠-2

I've done this part, but I'm not sure, if they could help me I'd appreciate it.

Comment: You mean: it is consistent if $a \ne -2$ - correct?

Comment: @Moo How did you get to that part?

Comment: @Nick Yes, a≠−2 I'll fix it

Comment: @Moo Perfect, what I do not understand is the last part of the divisions that, I did, but it does not give me that. =\ but thank you very much